# How to escape [ in app.config file?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, app-config

I have a query that needs to be read from app.config file. The query contains a regular expression. I am not able to specify character class within the regular expression value. The compiler does not recognize the character [. How do I escape it?

Here is my config file value

```
<add key="GetIds" value="select top 1000 Id from Table1 where  dbo.RegexMatch(TEXT, '&#[0-9]+;|&amp;', 0) > 0 "/>
```

where dbo.RegexMatch is a stored procedure that finds the given pattern in "TEXT".

I am getting an error that says "Invalid Character in a Decimal Number [."

Comment: My RegEx is &#[0-9]+;|&amp;

Comment: @ Vignesh Kumar: Tried it before asking the question here. Didn't work.

Comment: Please use stored procedures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use that

```
<add key="GetIds" value="select top 1000 Id from Table1 where  dbo.RegexMatch(TEXT, '&amp;&#35;&#91;0-9]+;|&amp;amp;', 0) > 0 "/>
```

You should replace `&`, `#` and `[` with their respecive [HTML codes](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm): `&amp;`, `&#35;` and `&#91;`.